Maximum possible speed of Mechas?
Similar, but asks for an answer in a specific case. Looking for a general purpose formula or other method of estimation.
Mecha appears to have two main problems—armouring and square cube law. These problems usually feed off one another—it’s impossible to put sufficient armour on because then the mecha becomes to heavy—and make it generally impractical for mechas when tanks would work fine and can be armoured.
In my setting—let’s call it Mechaville—, mecha technicians have realised the folly of trying to armour the mechas—the same reason knights stoped wearing full armour, musket rounds penetrated to easily. In Mechaville, the technicians have thus decided superior numbers and better speed are the way to go.
Given leg length (6-9 metres) and number of legs (2-6), is there a formula to derive an estimate of the maximum speed at which something can run?
 (If needed, the mass is around 2,000-2,500 kgs)

I think you really need to restrict the question further. I could go for legs of such length and then simply add a gun on top and some sensors. It could go really fast. It also depends on the type of legs, their aimed purpose (speed, urban, other?) and more. Restricting the question can give more accurate answers.

Four legs, each leg ending in a powered wheel. Can easily reach 160 km/h (100 mph).

Can they also have a jet boost? They might need (foldaway) short stubby wings for taking advantage of ground effect, or maybe skids are simpler. Would that work for you as a frame-challenge?

@Escapeddentalpatient., would there be enough fuel/propellant for that in the mass limit? Or are batteries and propellers the way to go at the mass specified?

@Escapeddentalpatient. they sound believable enough for me (and my healthy skepticism with ai). Turns out the T’au and their Battlesuits were onto something.

There's a formula used by paleontologists to estimate the speed of dinosaurs, I'm not sure how applicable it would be for mechas.  By comparing tracks, bones, and such that have been preserved in fossils to the behaviors of modern birds and reptiles the paleontologists believe they have a good estimate on the capabilities of dinosaurs.  Of course they are using models built on assumptions from live animals, which are made of muscle and bone, not steel and hydraulic fluid.

Are the mecha's legs following the movements of an operator's legs, or are the legs simply cycling in response to a throttle setting?

Mechas sink into the ground. Unless they have many legs, distributing the weight- forming a continuous load distribution band- almost a track. If those legs get damaged, they stick out- and form an obstacle. But lets assume, that over difficult terrain mechas are more useful. Which they kind of are:
There is that lumberjack walker:
http://www.theoldrobots.com/Walking-Robot2.html
Then there are spider-excavators for mountainous terrain:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0XSQY7KRmZk
Notice that this thing has wheels. Wheels are best on roads.
So, walkers are the fastest unit - on difficult terrain, like swamps, dense forests and mountains. Which makes them ideal- for partisans hiding abroad. Unfortunately, that is - often worthless terrain. As in you will have no infrastructure there to maintain robots and you will have no logistic structures. But they will be fast- for ground units. Still sitting ducks for helicopters, jets and drones. All it takes is one dirtbike riding drone pilot to deploy and take it out.
So speed is not the interesting thing, its more - the element of suprise. As in- how did they drag in artillery unseen over that mountain ridge, through the swamp. Thats impossible! It does not have to be fast for that- just has to be there, has to fire some sniper fire and relocate again. Nobody asks the guy in ghilly suite if he could win the 100 yard dash, thats what the 50 bmg bullet is here for.So the question is- how fast can you dash after a artillery strike, to get out of counter-battery-fire, scout drone range- and then hide your thermal profile and the route you came in. Ideally while being stealthy.
All that remains, is a artillery sniper drone, on legs, with a 2nd part carrying the ammunition, staying in hiding with the pilot. The shooter then deploys, lightweight, up a hill, all the while having the escape route nailed down- shoots, scoots and later reunites with the commander. If big mamma mecha and little ninja daddy mecha love each other very much, they go skinny dipping in swamp or mountain lake after the kill.
PS: Tanks have to constantly perform track maintenance while on the move. Mechas would have it even worse- these are mechanical systems- and excavator pistons need regular maintenance (every 500 h)- means every 20 days minimum. That is without dramatic anime landings or combat action. And no hydraulic blood loss.

Rule of Cool is in effect
See Meta entry here on Rule of Cool answers
The short answer
The more you try and rationalize and justify Mecha, the more you are going to draw attention to the various inherent problems with such a system, inviting the viewer to not suspend their disbelief and thus defeating the whole purpose of World Building.
Longer answer:
Mecha are Cool
There, I said it - Whether it is Pacific Rim, the monstrous thingy from Power Rangers, Mech Warrior etc - they all share one core component: Giant Robot tank-like walking vehicles running around causing all manner of Mayhem are awesome.
In fact, they are so Awesome that we will ignore the myriad of technical problems with them.
Yes - people will write nit-picking articles or Quora questions as to whether or not they are possible, but the reality is - when you are in the middle of the Story, Movie, Video Game, Whatever - do you really care that such a construct would sink into the ground due to Ground Pressure? Or that the force of impact would cause any occupants to be rendered into a Pulp?
NO
Because Mecha are Cool.
And this leads to the World Building process element - By attempting to justify certain aspects of your Mecha with real world physics, the more you are going to draw your reader out of your world, which runs counter to your goal.
In addition, mechanized processes can run incredibly fast - consider a classic 90s era Formula 1 V10 engine, screaming at nearly 20,000 RPM - the piston inside the engine was hitting nearly 11,000 G in acceleration, So long as you have sufficiently strong materials (Handwaivium) that is light and strong and a sufficiently powerful means of propulsion (IIRC Pacific Rim had Nuclear Reactors in their Jaegars) - there is no reason why a large object could not move at extremely fast speeds.
I therefore suggest that the best option is to simple state a speed (100 Kph, 200 Kph) and be done with it, rather than try to rationalize something with a Formula - trying to rationalize the irrational does not work with suspension of disbelief. And suspension of Disbelief is key to a successful World Building process.

Agree - there are so many engineering and non-engineering problems with having anything using 6+m legs that you just need to rely on suspension of disbelief. (Two non-engineering problems that leap out are a total inability for anything that tall to be able to hide and that wire obstacles would be very effective at tripping them - not hard to anchor a wire so that it can resist a ton or so of force.)

Battletech (game and novels, and thus the Mech Warrior series of video games and TTRPG) also has fusion engines powering battlemechs, aerotech fighters, etc. although some wheeled / tracked / hovercraft ground combat vehicles only use combustion engines. (It was designed before battery-electric vehicles were any good.)

Battletech has mech design rules which includes max speeds given engine size (power and mass) and mech mass; movement points per turn can be translated to m/s or km/h, so if you want to have mechs somewhat like that system, you could use similar numbers, like 20 ton mechs with big engines (using a significant fraction of their total mass on the engine) could walk ~88 kph, run ~130 kph.  Or faster if they spend even more of their mass on engines. (https://www.reddit.com/r/battletech/comments/2o52v3/btech_speed/). 100-ton mechs were the slowest, being at best ~44 kph walk / ~66 kph run.

Oh, I see the OP's mechs are much lighter than Battletech, only 2 to 2.5 (metric) tons.  But still similar leg length. (IIRC, bipedal battlemechs are about 12m tall.  I forget if quad mechs were supposed to be shorter.)  So they probably float like a cork in water even worse than battlemechs :P

No, there is no formula which can output a speed given only the variables of mass, leg length, and number of legs.
